# Add a casted string to a string array

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have the following code (simplified):

```
bar = ["foo"]  
baz = ""  
for i in range(5):  
    baz += str(i)  
bar += baz
```

That gives me the following value for `bar`:

```
["foo", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

However, I want the following value for `bar`:

```
["foo", "01234"]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Because += calls list.extend, use list.append.

Comment: Try `baz += [str(i)]` and `bar += [baz]`instead.

Answer (score 2):

When working with lists, the `+=` operator acts like `list.extend`.  In other words, it will take the characters in the `baz` string and append them to the `bar` list one-by-one.

To append the `baz` string as a whole, use [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
bar.append(baz)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst += 'def'  # Appends individual characters
>>> lst
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>>
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> lst.append('def')  # Appends whole string
>>> lst
['a', 'b', 'c', 'def']
>>>
```